# How to verify SSH keys properly added for Git?

Tags: git, ssh

What's the command to verify SSH keys are properly added for `git`? There are 2 sets of keys under our `~/.ssh/` and we want to add both of them. What we did was to run `ssh-add -l` in `git bash`:

```
$ ssh-add -l
2048 28:1b:b8:b2:a8:f1:9b:bb:b5:85:21:d5:d8:0b:00:b2 /c/Users/myuser/.ssh/bb_rsa (RSA)
2048 3d:31:e8:f7:f5:cd:dd:c7:0b:84:16:66:23:95:af:05 /c/Users/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)
```

> Are those 2 sets of SSH keys shown in command `ssh-add` properly added for git(both public and private)?

We are getting `permission denied` when deploying and would like to verify that the keys are added properly.

Comment: What do you mean by 'loaded'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You need to add only the public keys under your github account.

  - Set the remote url to ssh protocol if its not set already:
    `git remote set-url origin <url>`
  - Try to do any **remote** operation like:

    ```
    git fetch --all --prune
    git pull
    ```

If the ssh is not set correctly you will get an error message.

***Note***:
On the first operation you might get a question asking you if you wish to add the ssh key to the known hosts. Answer with yes and it will not prompt again.

#### If you keep getting the *Permission denied* error?

- Verify that the **github user** is a contributer to the project.

Comment: `Verify that the github user is a contributer to the project.`. This is the problem we are having. Thanks.